# many sql statements to one by checking every

Tags: mysql

Is it better to run one statement and not many ? How can I do it ?
Something like `SELECT * FROM tbl_brand as brand, tbl_model as model WHERE brand_id=?` ? and how to check is brand, model and other isnt empty if empty set it to $not_specified.

Other question for future can I use the same $statement to get other item or better I need to rename it to $statemen1 $statement2 $statement3 ?

**Thanks guys for help have a nice day.**

my bad I give you not full info.

```
<?php
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_car WHERE car_id and status=? ORDER BY car_id DESC LIMIT 6;");
$statement->execute(array(1));
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                           
foreach ($result as $row)
{
    $n_car_id = $row['car_id'];
    $n_brand_id = $row['brand_id'];
    $n_model_id = $row['model_id'];
    $n_fuel_id = $row['fuel_id'];
    $n_transmission_id = $row['transmission_id'];
    $n_engine_id = $row['engine_id'];
    $n_seller_id = $row['seller_id'];
    
    // Check if this seller is active or inactive
    $statement1 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_seller WHERE seller_id=? AND seller_access=?");
    $statement1->execute(array($n_seller_id,1));
    $seller_status = $statement1->rowCount();
    if(!$seller_status) {continue;}

    $today = date('Y-m-d');

    $valid = 0;
    $statement1 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_payment WHERE seller_id=? AND payment_status=?");
    $statement1->execute(array($n_seller_id,'Completed'));
    $result1 = $statement1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                         
    foreach ($result1 as $row1) {
        if(($today>=$row1['payment_date'])&&($today<=$row1['expire_date'])) {
            $valid = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($valid == 1)
    {
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_brand WHERE brand_id=?");
        $statement->execute(array($n_brand_id));
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                           
        $total = $statement->rowCount();
        if($total) {
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $n_brand_name = $row['brand_name'];
            }
        } else {
            $n_brand_name = $not_specified;
        }
        
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_model WHERE model_id=?");
        $statement->execute(array($n_model_id));
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                           
        $total = $statement->rowCount();
        if($total) {
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $n_model_name = $row['model_name'];
            }
        } else {
            $n_model_name = $not_specified;
        }
        
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_fuel WHERE fuel_id=?");
        $statement->execute(array($n_fuel_id));
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                           
        $total = $statement->rowCount();
        if($total) {
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $n_fuel_name = $row['fuel_name'];
            }
        } else {
            $n_fuel_name = $not_specified;
        }
        
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_transmission WHERE transmission_id=?");
        $statement->execute(array($n_transmission_id));
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                           
        $total = $statement->rowCount();
        if($total) {
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $n_transmission_name = $row['transmission_name'];
            }
        } else {
            $n_transmission_name = $not_specified;
        }
        
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_engine WHERE engine_id=?");
        $statement->execute(array($n_engine_id));
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                           
        $total = $statement->rowCount();
        if($total) {
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $n_engine_name = $row['engine_name'];
            }
        } else {
            $n_engine_name = $not_specified;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_car` (
  `car_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brand_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `model_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `body_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fuel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `transmission_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `engine_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `year` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `mileage` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `regular_price` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `sale_price` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `seller_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`car_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_brand` (
  `brand_id` tinyint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brand_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`brand_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=64 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_model` (
  `model_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `model_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`model_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=400 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

fuel,transmission and other looks the same :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_fuel`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_fuel` (
  `fuel_id` tinyint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fuel_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fuel_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: you could probably make this more efficient by using a series of `LEFT JOIN` clauses in your first SQL statement - one for each of the additional related tables.  As long as you have indices defined on those columns, this should increase performance and make your code shorter.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what the purpose of your `WHERE car_id` constraint is.  Is `car_id` the primary key on your `tbl_car` table?  If so, this clause is always going to be true, so you could just omit it and instead just have `WHERE status=?`

Answer (score 0):

This should get all the info you need in one query.  Please note:

- I'm assuming `tbl_payment.payment_date` and `tbl_payment.expire_date` are MySQL `date` columns.  Therefore I've optimised things a bit by using MySQL's `CURDATE()` function, rather than passing in the output of PHP's `date()` function.  If your PHP installation and your MySQL server are configured for different timezones (unlikely if you're on the same host), you might want to tweak that.
- I've added a `DISTINCT` clause just in case there are multiple valid payments per car.  This `DISTINCT` clause means you will only ever get one row per car, even in this case.
- The `INNER JOIN` tables mean there *must* be a matching row in the other table, the row from `tbl_car` will not be included in the output if there is no matching row in the other table
- The `LEFT JOIN` tables mean there *may* be a matching row in the other table, but the row from `tbl_car` will always be included even if there is no matching row in the other table
- I switched from using positional parameters in the SQL to named parameters, as it makes the code easier to read

This should mean you get all the info you need from one call to the database, rather than 43 database calls you had originally.

NB It's not necessary, but you could make this query run even faster by adding indices on each of the foreign key columns in `tbl_car`.

```
<?php
$statement = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT DISTINCT
      tbl_car.*,
      tbl_brand.brand_name,
      tbl_model.model_name,
      tbl_fuel.fuel_name,
      tbl_transmission.transmission_name,
      tbl_engine.engine_name
    FROM tbl_car
    INNER JOIN tbl_seller ON tbl_car.seller_id = tbl_seller.seller_id
    INNER JOIN tbl_payment ON tbl_car.seller_id = tbl_payment.seller_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_brand ON tbl_car.brand_id = tbl_brand.brand_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_model ON tbl_car.model_id = tbl_model.model_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_fuel ON tbl_car.fuel_id = tbl_fuel.fuel_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_transmission ON tbl_car.transmission_id = tbl_transmission.transmission_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_engine ON tbl_car.engine_id = tbl_engine.engine_id
    WHERE tbl_car.status = :car_status
    AND tbl_seller.seller_access = :seller_access
    AND tbl_payment.payment_status = :payment_status
    AND CURDATE() BETWEEN tbl_payment.payment_date AND tbl_payment.expire_date
    ORDER BY tbl_car.car_id DESC
    LIMIT 6
');
$statement->execute([
    'car_status' => 1,
    'seller_access' => 1,
    'payment_status' => 'Completed',
]);
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                           
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $n_car_id = $row['car_id'];
    $n_brand_id = $row['brand_id'];
    $n_model_id = $row['model_id'];
    $n_fuel_id = $row['fuel_id'];
    $n_transmission_id = $row['transmission_id'];
    $n_engine_id = $row['engine_id'];
    $n_seller_id = $row['seller_id'];
    $n_brand_name = $row['brand_name'] ?? $not_specified;
    $n_model_name = $row['model_name'] ?? $not_specified;
    $n_fuel_name = $row['fuel_name'] ?? $not_specified;
    $n_transmission_name = $row['transmission_name'] ?? $not_specified;
    $n_engine_name = $row['engine_name'] ?? $not_specified;

    // the rest of your code here
}
```

Comment: Sorry bro, I posted not full code and without mysql tables. I edited my post. I tried integrate your code into my but I fail :D Tried use your code after `if($valid == 1)`. But what I need to use in `WHERE tbl_car.status=?` ? Or better to change whole code with checking user status in one mysql? Thanks.

Comment: OK, that looks just like we need to add two more tables - `tbl_seller` and `tbl_payment`.  I'll adjust my answer to include those

Comment: Getting some errors. Can't find solution what's wrong. Sorry if I disturbing you. Thanks.

mysql 5.7.26 (wampserver). 136 line is `'status' => 1,`
if I remove `tbl_seller ` I get error for next line `tbl_payment`.

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM tbl_car INNER JOIN tbl_seller ON tbl_car.seller_id = tbl_seller.seller' at line 7 in C:\wamp64\www\index.php on line 136
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the syntax error is.  Are you using the SQL statement exactly as in the answer, or adding any extra fields?  Please can you add the table structure for tbl_seller and tbl_payment and I'll see if I can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I took a guess at the table structure for `tbl_seller` and `tbl_payment` using the information from your question.  The SQL statement runs fine for me.  Please can you check again the actual SQL you are running?

Comment: I removed the `tbl_engine` from your code because I deleted the `tbl_engine table` so the user can write their own capacity. If I just paste your code I get the same error.

removed:
`tbl_engine.engine_name
LEFT JOIN tbl_engine ON tbl_car.engine_id = tbl_engine.engine_id
$n_engine_id = $row['engine_id'];`

There is limitted characters in this comments so in `tbl_seller` there is `seller_id` and other seller info `seller_access` is 0 or 1.
inside `tbl_payment` there is `id`, `seller_id`, `payment_status`.
Tried to change dates from `2023-04-28` to mysql `20230428`. Didn't helped.

Comment: Rob Eyre, lol I just forget to remove `,` after `tbl_transmission.transmission_name,`. Thank you very much for your time.